# Custom hook to check window width

Tags: reactjs

So I have a customer hook that returns whether the window width is smaller than 768 or not. I'm doing this to check for usage in mobile vs laptop.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const getIsMobile = () => window.innerWidth <= 768;


function CheckMobileHook() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(getIsMobile());
  useEffect(() => {
    const onResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(getIsMobile());
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return isMobile;
}

export default CheckMobileHook;
```

This onResize method is getting called everytime and also there is a state change.

So I would like to do something like -

```
 const onResize = useCallback(() => {
     setIsMobile(getIsMobile());
  },[getIsMobile()]
```

But passing a function in the dependency array won't make any sense.
I know this is wrong but how can I only make this state change when the window width is either smaller or greater than 768?

**I was doing this to learn useCallback**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good scenario for `useCallback`, which is used when a costly function is ran upon every re-render. To optimize in case of a costly function, `useCallback` allows us to *kinda* memoize a function and only run it if the dependency prop changes.

In your case, there's no getting around calling `onResize`. That's the entire point of the window resize event listener, after all.

However, if you're thinking to avoid running the `setIsMobile` state setter unless necessary, and simply use a conditional, something like this:

```
const onResize = () => {
    if (getIsMobile() < 768) {
      setIsMobile(getIsMobile());
    }
};
```

You now run into the react hook rule which dictates we don't run hooks inside conditions.

So, what you should keep in mind here is that the React virtual DOM was built to handle situations like this with ease. The VDOM is very efficient, as opposed to actually doing a repaint to the DOM, which would be disastrous performance wise.

In summary, this isn't a good use case for `useCallback`. The `useState` hook is very lightweight, and `useCallback` is intended for functions that create significant performance hits.

Comment: Yes, now i understand this :)